# The "-igan" ending

Tags: etymology, suffixes

Does the *-igan* suffix serve the same function in the following words?

- shenan**igan**
- card**igan**
- hool**igan**

If so, what does it mean? Where does it come from?

Comment: Most people wouldn't agree *backyardigan* is a "word" at all. I think *cardigan* derives from the ***name*** (Earl of Cardigan?). And nobody really knows the etymology of [hooligan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooliganism), but I don't see any reason to think *-igan* is in any meaningful sense a "suffix". In short, the question is either Not Constructive or Too Localised.

Comment: Don’t forget *barrigan*, *corrigan*, *larrigan*, *mulligan*, *ptarmigan*, *shenanigans*, *starrigan*, *toboggan*, and *wanigan*  while you’re at it.  If you dig just a wee bit, you will actually find that most of those share something interesting in common. @FumbleFingers take note.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't know it makes much difference that the sequence is somewhat associated with Irish/Welsh words. I can't see it "means" anything (which to me means it's not *in any meaningful sense a "suffix".* :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Just because _you_ don't recognize it doesn't mean there's not a pattern.

Comment: @Mitch: Yeah, I guess. But the only pattern I see is "Celtishness", and that doesn't seem to apply to the only "productive suffix" example I know - the Canadian kids tv show *Backyardigans*. If there's a pattern, *they* probably weren't tapping into it.

Comment: I don't see anything _too localised_ about this question. +1

Comment: And *toboggan* and *Michigan* both come from American Indian words, so they're not all Celtic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Cardigan* and *hooligan* probably come from the Welsh name [Ceredigion](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cardigan) and the Irish name [Houlighan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hooligan&searchmode=none), respectively. The Welsh name *Ceredigion* means "Ceredig's land". There are a lot of Irish names that end in *-gan, -han* or *-ghan*. If we go by the etymologies I can find for [Monaghan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaghan#Etymology) and [Mulligan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mulligan) the *-an* is a diminuitive. So these two are not that closely related, but *mulligan* and *hooligan* may be, since they're both from Irish names ending with the same diminuitive.

I should point out that the Irish name *O Huallachain* can be spelled *Houligan, Houlihan,* or *Houlighan* in English, so these three suffixes indeed have the same origin.

Comment: *Cardigan* is an eponym from George Brudenell, Earl of Cardigan in the Crimean War. Perhaps if he had been less interested in clothing he might not have led the Charge of the Light Brigade.

Comment: @TimLymington - There were two George Brudenells styled Earl of Cardigan (the 3rd and 4th Earl respectively), both safely dead long before the six hundred rode into the Valley of Death themselves, sent there by 7th Earl -- the great-great-grandson and great-grandson of those Georges -- James Thomas Brudenell.

Comment: So the earlier earls were now late.